# Entity Framework matching a subset of an int

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3, ef-code-first

I am implementing a search where I would like to partially match an entity's primary key. For example, if I would search for "123" it would return entities which have primary keys like:

- 12345
- 67123
- 91234

If this were a string, I'd attack it like this:

```
    public PartialViewResult QuickSearch(string searchTerm)
    {
        var results = db.MyEntities.Where(x => x.myProperty.Contains(searchTerm));
        return PartialView("QuickSearch_Results", results);
    }
```

However I'm at a loss on the best way to do this for an int. I'm looking for something like this:

```
    public PartialViewResult QuickSearch(int id)
    {
        var results = db.MyEntities.Where(x => x.myPropertyId.Contains(int));
        return PartialView("QuickSearch_Results", results);
    }
```

But obviously contains is not the right way to go. What would be a correct way of implementing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Totally wild and untested guess using the [StringConvert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487127.aspx) method:

```
public PartialViewResult QuickSearch(int id)
{
    string sId = id.ToString();
    var results = 
        from x in db.MyEntities
        where SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)x.myPropertyId)
                          .Contains(sId)
        select x;
    return PartialView("QuickSearch_Results", results);
}
```

Comment: I had never seen the SqlFunctions class before. Thanks for sharing. +1

Comment: I'm getting "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression." Trying a few things, any ideas?

Comment: @macca1, please check if my updated answer works. I have moved the .ToString call out of the expression hoping to cheat EF. God, I am so glad I don't have to use EF in my current project :-)

Comment: Aaaaaand my code contains more unnecessary voodoo-stuff now... But worked good, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
db.MyEntities.Where(x => x.myPropertyId.ToString().Contains(id.ToString()));
```

Comment: I did think to try this one out but was getting the same error I've posted to Darin's suggestion.

Comment: Yep, your right. I didn't test this. Apparently this would only work with an object query. @Darin's answer is obviously what you need, and at the same time taught me something new.